# Acquiring Extension in source followed by extra text using regex

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to get multiple links ending with the extensions flv.

My regex is as follows `src\s*=\s*"(.+?\.flv.*)"`

The link is [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=src%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%22(.%2B%3F%5C.flv.*)%22&test_string=%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20class%3D%22report_video%22%20data-video-id%3D%2231920%22%20title%3D%22Report%20Video%22%3EVideo%20Broken%3F%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22vmargin%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fplaybb.me%2Fembed.php%3Fw%3D718%26h%3D438%26vid%3DF%2Ffull-metal-panic-fummofu-12.flv%22%20style%3D%22width%3A718px%3Bheight%3A438px%3Bborder%3A0%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3B%22%20%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20class%3D%22report_video%22%20data-video-id%3D%2231921%22%20title%3D%22Report%20Video%22%3EVideo%20Broken%3F%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22vmargin%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Feasyvideo.me%2Fgogo%2F%3Fw%3D718%26h%3D438%26file%3Dfullmetalpanicfomuffo-12.flv%26sv%3D1%22%20style%3D%22width%3A718px%3Bheight%3A438px%3Bborder%3A0%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3B%22%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20class%3D%22report_video%22%20data-video-id%3D%22198602%22%20title%3D%22Report%20Vid&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

However, I also get the text lying out of the double quotes. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Take a look at the match captures (Match 1) in your link. It already has what you are looking for. Since you have defined a capturing group `(.+?\.flv.*)` using parenthesis all the matched characters inside of your capturing group will be available in the first matched group.

Comment: Might be better to match `[^"]` than `.` within a quoted string.  E.g. `src\s*=\s*"([^"]+\.flv[^"]*)"` *or* the non-greedy quantifier (`?`) -> `src\s*=\s*"(.+?\.flv.*?)"` so that it doesn't match content between consecutive links.

Comment: Ah, I just seen the link... I'll write that up as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src\s*=\s*"(.+?\.flv.*?)"` ([link](http://pythex.org/?regex=src%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%22(.%2B%3F%5C.flv.*)%22&test_string=%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20class%3D%22report_video%22%20data-video-id%3D%2231920%22%20title%3D%22Report%20Video%22%3EVideo%20Broken%3F%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22vmargin%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fplaybb.me%2Fembed.php%3Fw%3D718%26h%3D438%26vid%3DF%2Ffull-metal-panic-fummofu-12.flv%22%20style%3D%22width%3A718px%3Bheight%3A438px%3Bborder%3A0%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3B%22%20%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20class%3D%22report_video%22%20data-video-id%3D%2231921%22%20title%3D%22Report%20Video%22%3EVideo%20Broken%3F%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22vmargin%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Feasyvideo.me%2Fgogo%2F%3Fw%3D718%26h%3D438%26file%3Dfullmetalpanicfomuffo-12.flv%26sv%3D1%22%20style%3D%22width%3A718px%3Bheight%3A438px%3Bborder%3A0%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3B%22%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20class%3D%22report_video%22%20data-video-id%3D%22198602%22%20title%3D%22Report%20Vid&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0))

`.*` consumes all the other attributes on the same line. `.*?` tells the matcher to match as few characters as possible, because `+` and `*` in regex are 'greedy'.